# How to make sure child contract address appears in transaction details when created by a factory contract?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, dapp-development, internal-transactions

When you look up a transaction hash on a site like etherscan their are fields like `to`, `from` and `create`. What can I do so that the field `create` has the address of the child contract deployed instead of it being null?

Or am I asking the wrong question? What is the purpose of the `create` field?

Comment: Create is usually shown when the field `to` is empty, so the transaction is deploying a contract. They show some details when staking or swaping tokens, but I haven't seen them showing details for factory contracts.